# Regular expression: Changing part of a line starting with a character

Tags: regex, textmate

I am trying to write a regular expression that finds lines starting with '@' and finds a particular character and replaces it. Concretely, I want to find lines such as:

```
@xxxxxx{yyy/zzz
```

and replace this with

```
@xxxxxx{yyy_zzz
```

(xxxxxx, yyy and zzz do not have /)

I can come up with the following that starts from the beginning of a line and finds the first /

```
^(.*?)/(.*?)
```

then I can change this with

```
$1_$2
```

But this picks up more lines with / in them and I want to focus them on lines that start with @. I would appreciate help. I am doing this within Textmate, to be more specific.

Comment: Just add an `@` to the beginning of your regex: `^(@.*?)/(.*?)/`

Comment: Thank you Nick, this works (I thought I had added this comment yesterday, but I must have done something wrong since it did not show up).

Comment: you did do it yesterday, thank you. SO has a policy of deleting "thank you" comments, so that's probably what happened to it.

Comment: I learn something new every day... Didn't know that policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^(@.*?)\/(.*)` will get @xxxxxx{yyy and zzz in the groups 1 and 2 for @xxxxxx{yyy/zzz. Note that I escaped /. You might need to change that depending on the language you're using.

I used to use the website below for my assignments. It might help you for your next regular expressions.

**WEBSITE**: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

**Not** being an Expert in Textmate, I hope this will Work:

```
(?<=@.*?)\/
```

It Works by looking behind for a '`@`' sign followed by any number of any sign and finally the slash. The match will consist only of the slash, easy to replace the match with the underscore.

Comment: Thank you Paul. Unfortunately it gives a "invalid pattern in look-behind".

Comment: I was afraid of that, not all Regex flavors support that.